Does the Raspberry Pi 2B support wireless?
Question: Does the Raspberry Pi 2B support wireless functionality or just ethernet?
Is a WIFI USB Dongle required for wireless access?

Hey @jsotola, this question was answered by the author. —Best

@Seamus his questions was answered by its author —Best

Yes! Indeed the Raspberry Pi 2 does not have in-built wireless functionalities but can gain wireless access through a wifi-adapter that supports GNU/Linux (such as the TPE-N150USB).
Ethernet is supported by default
